# Setting visibility of MenuItems issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-optionsmenu, menu-items

I'm trying to set different `MenuItems` to each of my app's tabs (ActionBar Navigation Tabs). I've tried many solutions but the last seems to be the closest. When i open my app it hides my `MenuItem` , but when i swipe to second Fragment it doesn't show the `MenuItem` in spite of the fact that ive set that it has to be visible.

Do you have any idea, how to solve this?

See my code below (please check mainly the statements near notes "**Here**"):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EditText mEditText;
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    ProgressBar oProgressBar;
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    ViewPager mPager;
    ActionBar mActionBar;
    Menu mMenu;
    Tab mTab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.initialize(this, "code", "code");

        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Animal.class);
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        Log.v("Initialize", "intitalizing from Parse.com app");

        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        };

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm);

        mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);



        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {


            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab mTab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab mTab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                 mPager.setCurrentItem(mTab.getPosition());
                 mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
                 supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();  //Here


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab mTab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };



        ActionBar.Tab Animals = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Animals");
        ActionBar.Tab Frag2Tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Favorites");
        ActionBar.Tab Frag3Tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Settings");


        Animals.setTabListener(tabListener);
        Frag2Tab.setTabListener(tabListener);
        Frag3Tab.setTabListener(tabListener);


        mActionBar.addTab(Animals);
        mActionBar.addTab(Frag2Tab);
        mActionBar.addTab(Frag3Tab);

    }



    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
         System.exit(0);
     }


    @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        Fragment1 frg1 = new Fragment1();
        Fragment2 frg2 = new Fragment2();
        Fragment3 frg3 = new Fragment3();


        try {
            if(frg1.isMenuVisible()){


                    menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setEnabled(false) .setTitle("").setIcon(null);
                    Log.v("fdsfad", "sadfasdfsa");

                            }
            else if (frg2.isMenuVisible()){


                    menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setEnabled(true) .setTitle("Refresh").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh);
                    Log.v("fdsfad", "sadfasdfsa");

                            }

            else if (frg3.isMenuVisible()){


                menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setEnabled(true) .setTitle("Refresh").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh);
                    Log.v("fdsfad", "sadfasdfsa");

                            }

    }   catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                                            }


        return true;

}
     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            return true;
        }




         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_refresh:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Pull to refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true; 
                 } 
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }



         @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Search button: clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }




         }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no more item visible, setVisible(true) will be not working.

One option is to null the icon, set empty title and disable this item. Or maybe clearing and inflating menu in onPrepareOptionsMenu again will be working well.

Comment: Thans for an answer. Ive tried the first solution, but it doesnt work. How should i inflate it?

Comment: For first solution:
Instead of line `menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(false)`
make `menuItem.setEnable(false)`, `menuItem.setTitle("")`, `menuItem.setIcon(null)`. and if you want to show item, do the opposite so setEnable true, setIcon with image, and setTitle with your title value.

Comment: W8 for moment i will try to make sample app

Comment: It's working in my project... maybe there is some problem in `frg2.isMenuVisible()` ?. Btw making new `Fragments` every `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is ultra unoptimal.
Please try someting like:
public static boolean firstTrue = true;

 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
 {
  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  if (firstTrue)
  {
   menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setEnabled(false).setTitle("").setIcon(null);
  }
  else
  {
   menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setEnabled(true).setTitle("Refresh");
  }
  firstTrue = !firstTrue;
  return true;
 }

Comment: Thanks a lot, it finally forks!! But it still doesnt appear in my third tab. Is there any way, how to set it for i.e. 4 tabs?

Comment: My code was just the example (fast for 2 tabs;]). You could use `mPager.getCurrentItem()`, and depending on tab index make your `IF/ELSE IF/` and so on in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`

Comment: So what do you recommend me for doind it for 4 tabs?

Comment: Like i said, make in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` something like:
`int currentTab = mPager.getCurrentItem();
if(currentItem == 0)
{ //show item }else if(currentItem == 1){ //hide item}else if(currentItem == 2){//something show or hide} ....`

Comment: yes, now i get it. But I still dont know, how to reference menu item, because the constructor Menu is defined for onPrepareOptionsMenu, not TabListener. How should I reference it in TabListener?

Comment: Don't change anything in `TabListener`... i'm constantly talking about `onPrepareOptionsMenu` insides

Comment: It finally works with all 3 tabs. Thanks again for your effort and sorry for my problems